# What is the proper data type to store a sum of microseconds in C

Tags: c, types

Considering that the number can be really large, would it be safe to use `unsigned long`?

FWIW, I'm adding up all the microseconds from an apache log, thus the number can get really large.

Comment: Your just have to read about data types. Finally you can read about it on Wikipedia (though it is not considered to be a reliable source). At least, there are books or another sites...

Comment: @PeteDarrow If you find one of the answers satisfactory, please click the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you can do to store a "really large" number with *standard* C is a `unsigned long long int`:

> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
>     ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2<sup>64</sup> − 1

That is defined in the C99+ standards. If you're willing/wanting to go above and beyond just what C can do, there's other extensions to look at, the first that comes to mind is the [GNU MP Bignum library](http://gmplib.org/).

A third alternative that I think you should consider is breaking it down into microseconds and seconds the way [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) does with a `timeeval` structure. That way you don't have to get into ridiculously sized numbers. You can always do the conversions yourself if you want to view the data in just microseconds.

Comment: I like the idea of breaking it down into microseconds and seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Given that the maximum value you can store in an `unsigned long` on a 32 bits platform is around 4G, these 4G microseconds translate to only 71 minutes.

On a 64 bits platform (beware on Windows long is always 32 bits, even on Windows 64 bits), then you can count microseconds for up to 4G times 71 minutes. This is huge: approximately 5800 centuries.

Answer: if your `unsigned long` is 64 bits, it's OK.

Comment: Sizes of `long` and `unsigned long` don't *really* have much to do with platform size. You can typically expect pointer sizes to match the OS architecture (i.e. `sizeof(void*)` to be 4  on a 32-bit system and 8 on a 64-bit), but for integral types, all bets are off.: even 8 and 16-bit systems can have 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. As noted on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), an `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits but I guess that can depend on your machine. With 32 bits you can represent numbers as big as 2^32 = 4294967296. 4294967296 micro seconds is 4294 seconds or a bit over 1 hour.

Do you need more? If you do, consider using an `unsigned long long` which is guaranteed to be 64 bits, it is C99 though. Otherwise you could always store the seconds separately in another variable like the timeval struct does it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use unsigned long integer.that size is 0 to 4294967295 bytes

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit unsigned integer would give you about 1 hour 11 minutes, counting in microseconds:

```
4,294.967295 seconds
```

A 64-bit unsigned integer, on the other hand, would give you more than half a million years.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long integer is the best option to store big size data.
```

Answer (score 0):

32bit will certainly be too small, `unsigned long long` seems the right choice, It's guaranteed to be at least 64bit.  Or use `unit64_t` in `<inttypes.h>`, which is theoretically more portable.

It will be approximately over 500 million years, that should be enough.^_^

Answer (score 0):

`unistd.h` declares `useconds_t`.

---

**Update** referring to the question's body not to its title:

Count seconds using `time_t` and just store the remainder in micro seconds using `useconds_t`. This keeps your sources 100% portable.

---

**Update 2**

I just dicovered that my recent Debian declares `suseconds_t` to be `long int`.

Comment: A comment in my /usr/include/sys/types.h file: /*
 * Type useconds_t is an unsigned integral type capable of storing
 * values at least in the range of zero to 1,000,000.
 */
typedef uint_t          useconds_t;     /* Time, in microseconds */
This probably will not work for what the OP wants.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: Absolutely! However it answers the question implied by the title.